# Video produced from images only plays in VLC but no other players

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc-media-player

Within my folder with bunch of 13MP bmp images named 0001.bmp, 0002.bmp,... I run the following commands from command line.

Crop images to 4K

```
ffmpeg -i %4d.bmp -vf "crop=3840:2160:184:240" croped%4d.bmp
```

Scale images

```
ffmpeg -i croped%4d.bmp -vf scale=1920:1080 scaled%4d.bmp
```

Compress images to video

```
ffmpeg -r 25 -i scaled%4d.bmp -c:v libx264 -b:v 25000k -minrate 25000k -r 25 -s 1920x1080 -c:v libx264 -qp 20 -preset medium output.mp4
```

But the produced video can only be played in VLC, every other player fails.

Can anyone with more experience in ffmpeg suggest where I'm making a mistake?

This is the ffmpeg console output after the last command:

```
ffmpeg version N-47062-g26c531c Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Nov 25 2012 12:21:26 with gcc 4.7.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-pthreads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enab
le-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libop
encore-amrwb --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libnut --enable-libop
enjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheo
ra --enable-libutvideo --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-lib
vpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52.  9.100 / 52.  9.100
  libavcodec     54. 77.100 / 54. 77.100
  libavformat    54. 37.100 / 54. 37.100
  libavdevice    54.  3.100 / 54.  3.100
  libavfilter     3. 23.102 /  3. 23.102
  libswscale      2.  1.102 /  2.  1.102
  libswresample   0. 17.101 /  0. 17.101
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
[image2 @ 0202f180] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #0, image2, from 'scaled%4d.bmp': Duration: 00:00:04.96, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: bmp, bgr24, 1920x1080, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[libx264 @ 037792c0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 FastShuffle SSE4.2
[libx264 @ 037792c0] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 4.0, 4:4:4 8-bit
[libx264 @ 037792c0] 264 - core 128 r2216 198a7ea - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2012 - ht
tp://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subm
e=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,
11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=4 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 in
terlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 wei
ghtb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc=cqp mbtree=0 qp=
20 ip_ratio=1.40 pb_ratio=1.30 aq=0
Output #0, mp4, to 'video.mp4':
  Metadata:    encoder         : Lavf54.37.100
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv444p, 1920x1080, q=-1--1, 25000 kb/s, 1280 0 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:    Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (bmp -> libx264)
frame=  124 fps=2.9 q=-1.0 Lsize=   42311kB time=00:00:04.88 bitrate=71027.1kbits/s
video:42309kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.005367%
[libx264 @ 037792c0] frame I:1     Avg QP:17.00  size:579142
[libx264 @ 037792c0] frame P:93    Avg QP:20.00  size:375357
[libx264 @ 037792c0] frame B:30    Avg QP:22.00  size:261208
[libx264 @ 037792c0] consecutive B-frames: 51.6% 48.4%  0.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 037792c0] mb I  I16..4:  3.5% 77.5% 19.0%
[libx264 @ 037792c0] mb P  I16..4:  2.6% 47.2% 11.4%  P16..4: 10.3% 16.7% 11.7%  0.0%  0.0%    skip: 0.1%
[libx264 @ 037792c0] mb B  I16..4:  2.0% 34.1%  3.8%  B16..8: 20.3% 13.7%  6.3%  direct:19.0%  skip: 0.9%
L0:39.1% L1:20.8% BI:40.1%
[libx264 @ 037792c0] 8x8 transform intra:78.6% inter:63.5%
[libx264 @ 037792c0] coded y,u,v intra: 99.6% 72.4% 80.8% inter: 91.1% 65.5% 75.5%
[libx264 @ 037792c0] i16 v,h,dc,p:  7%  7% 54% 32%
[libx264 @ 037792c0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 10% 17% 32%  5%  6%  6%  8%  6% 10%
[libx264 @ 037792c0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu:  9% 12% 23%  9% 10%  8% 11%  7% 10%
[libx264 @ 037792c0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 037792c0] ref P L0: 31.1% 12.4% 30.4% 26.0%
[libx264 @ 037792c0] ref B L0: 58.7% 41.3%
[libx264 @ 037792c0] kb/s:69876.70
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why not do everything in one `ffmpeg` command instead of three?

Comment: Well. I haven't tried it, but I will. In case of problems I'll be back :)

Comment: That'd be: `ffmpeg -r 25 -i scaled%4d.bmp -vf "crop=3840:2160:184:240, scale=1920:1080" -c:v libx264 -b:v 25000k -minrate 25000k -r 25 -s 1920x1080 -c:v libx264 -qp 20 -preset medium output.mp4` for combining everything.

Comment: Thanks slhck! Just a minor change: instead of scaled%4d.bmp it's %4d.bmp... BR

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you convert from BMP, JPG or PNG files, `ffmpeg` will try to preserve as much detail as possible and encode the video with the best matching color space. Your resulting file uses the `yuv444p` [non-subsampled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling) colorspace. JPGs use `yuv422p`. Many players cannot show video in this format, such as Windows Media Player, QuickTime and others.

To get a video supported in non-FFmpeg-based players, use this command, with the most important thing being the `-pix_fmt yuv420p` option.

Note that I removed your other options for the sake of brevity.

```
ffmpeg … -i scaled%4d.bmp -c:v libx264 … -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

By the way, your `ffmpeg` is rather old. Please [update to a new version](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html). Recent versions warn you of the color space being YUV 4:4:4 and that incompatible players might not show the video or even crash.

Comment: Thanks slhck! Now, my video can be run by other players. And I'll update ffmpeg for sure... Cheers!

Comment: Worth noting: I've been playing with ffmpeg options, and it looks like Apple Quicktime can't handle h265, so stick with h264. (Vlc can play h265.)

Comment: @EdwardFalk QuickTime can handle HEVC, see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207022 – which OS version do you have?

Comment: I have Mojave; 10.14.6

Comment: If I do `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec libx264 output.mp4`, my Mac is happy to play the video. If I use libx265 instead, the resulting file does not display in finder or play in Quicktime. I get the message "The file isn’t compatible with QuickTime Player.".  VLC is happy to play it, however.

Comment: Update: this blog had the answer: https://brandur.org/fragments/ffmpeg-h265. The key was the "-tag:v hvc1" option. The recommended command is `ffmpeg -i input.mov -c:v libx265 -preset fast -crf 28 -tag:v hvc1 -c:a eac3 -b:a 224k output.mov`

Comment: One more comment: if your video is already h.265, but won't play on Quicktime, you can quickly add the required tag like so: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -codec copy -tag:v hvc1 output.mp4`

Comment: @EdwardFalk Good to know. QuickTime is a bit special …

Comment: Yeah, it never ends. I found that Zoom would not use my h.265 videos for a live background, so I switch to h.264 anyway.